# Identical query, tables, but different EXPLAIN and performance

Tags: mysql, performance, explain, query-performance

I have two tables `levels` and `users_favorites`

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 | int(9)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_id            | int(10)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| level_name         | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| user_name          | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rating             | decimal(3,2) | NO   |     | 2.50    |       |
| votes              | int(5)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| plays              | int(5)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| date_published     | date         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| user_comment       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| playable_character | int(2)       | NO   | MUL | 1       |       |
| is_featured        | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
+----------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id  | int(8) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| level_id | int(8) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have my local dev environment and the production servers. This query:

```
SELECT id, level_name, date_published, rating
FROM levels
WHERE id IN (SELECT level_id FROM users_favorites WHERE user_id = 2);
```

runs very fast locally (around 0.0x seconds) and very slow on production (~15 seconds). The EXPLAIN's are different. On local:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows Extra
1   SIMPLE  users_favorites ref uniq_user_level,idx_user    idx_user    4   const   21  "Using index"
1   SIMPLE  levels  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   users_favorites.level_id    1   "Using where"
```

And on production:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY levels  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3368988 "Using where"
2   "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY"    users_favorites eq_ref  uniq_user_level,idx_user    uniq_user_level 8   const,func  1   "Using index"
```

I know the data is the the same because it was imported and exported from the same schema. I've run OPTIMIZE and made sure the indexes are the same, tried forcing the indexes. Nothing worked.

The only difference I can spot is the version of MySQL: locally it's 5.6.10, on production it's 5.5.34-log. If that's the reason, I'll upgrade, but I'm wondering if there could some other reason? Or way to phrase the query so it always reduces by the subquery first, as it does locally: 21 rows instead of 3368988?

TIA

Comment: Before I post an answer, one question: Is there a reason this is written as a subquery when it seems like it would be better written as a join, and presumably less ambiguous to the optimizer in 5.5?  SELECT l.id, l.level_name, l.date_published, l.rating FROM levels l JOIN users_favorites uf ON uf.level_id = l.id WHERE uf.user_id = 2 ... if that is as logically equivalent as it seems like it would be, how does that query look with `EXPLAIN` on 5.5?  (Okay, that might be two questions).

Comment: @sqlbot, "Is there a reason this is written as a subquery when it seems like it would be better written as a join." Yes, the answer being that apparently I'm not that great at SQL. I tried the query as you suggested and it gave the same `EXPLAIN` on 5.5 and 5.6 and was identical to my subquery's `EXPLAIN` on 5.5. So, in short your `JOIN` gave the result I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a simple join. Sub-queries does not provide the best result quite often

```
EXPLAIN SELECT l.id, l.level_name, l.date_published, l.rating
FROM levels AS l
INNER JOIN users_favorites AS uf 
ON uf.level_id = l.id
WHERE l.user_id = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks. What would be the motivation of the `INNER` join? Without it, I get very very slightly faster results (fetch time is always zero without `INNER`, whereas with it, I get a small fetch time.

Comment: Do compare the speed of the actual queries, you need to ignore the query cache. To profile atleast use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * from xxx...`. Please read on "performance of  sub-query in MySQL" and you will find the answer.

Comment: I used the `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE`. The query without the `INNER` on the `JOIN` is still consistently a little faster.

Comment: Next step :) 
Run the query `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * ....` and then  `SHOW WARNINGS`. That will show you the actual query running under the hood. Check out how your sub-queries & join queries are re-structured

Comment: Thanks, an interesting study. In the end I actually found no difference if `INNER` was used. Under the hood they were identical.

Comment: Cool. But if you know its join running in the end, try to remove the subquery. The query re-write might not be consistent always

Comment: Oh yeah, it was definitely better without the subquery :)